# Tracking eigenvectors of a 1-parameter family of matrices

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvector

My problem is this: I'm attempting a spectral decomposition of a random process via a (truncated) Karhunen-Loeve transform, but my covariance matrix is actually a 1-parameter family of matrices, and I need a way to estimate / visualize how my random process depends on this parameter.  To do this, I need a way to track the eigenvectors produced by numpy.linalg.eigh().

To give you an idea of my issue, here's a sample toy problem:  Suppose I have a set of points {xs}, and a random process R with covariance C(x,y) = 1/(1+a*(x-y)^2) which depends on the parameter a.  For a random sample of grid points in the range [0,1] and a given choice of a (say, a=1), I can populate my covariance matrix and implement the Karhunen-Loeve transform using:

```
num_x = 1000
xs = numpy.array([numpy.random.uniform() for i in range(num_x)])
z=numpy.random.standard_normal(num_x)
a0=1
def cov(x,y,a=a0): return 1/(1+a*(x-y)^2)
cov_m = numpy.array(map(lambda y: map(lambda x: cov(x,y),xs),xs))
w,v=numpy.linalg.eigh(cov_m)
R=numpy.dot(v,z*w^0.5)
```

This will give me realizations of R with values defined at each of my random grid points xs.  What I need to be able to do, however, is - for a specific realization (which means a specific choice of my grid xs and my random coefficients z) - track how R varies with respect to the parameter a in my covariance function.

This would be easy to do if I could compute the covariance matrix symbolically and specify a after the fact.  However, for large matrices this is not a plausible option.  The alternative method is to find a way to keep track of each eigenvector returned by numpy.linalg.eigh().  Unfortunately, numpy appears to be reordering them so as to always list the smallest eigenvalue first; this means that, when I vary a, the eigenvectors get reordered unpredictably, and the dot product numpy.dot(v,z*w^0.5) is no longer assigning the same coefficient to the same eigenvector.

Is there a way around this?

(This is a cross-post from ASKSAGE.  My implementation is using Sage, but as the question is not Sage specific and as there seems to be more activity here I thought I'd repost.  My apologies if cross-posting is not acceptable; if so please delete this.)

EDIT: Based on the conversation below, I see I need to add more detail about the nature of this problem.

The idea behind a Karhunen-Loeve transform is to decompose a random process R(x) spectrally, as follows:

R(x) = \sum_{i} Z_i \lambda_i^{1/2} \phi^{(i)}(x),

where each Z_i is an i.i.d. random variable with the standard normal distribution, each \phi^{(i)}(x) is a non-random function of x determined by the solution of the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, and each \lambda_i is the corresponding eigenvalue associated with \phi^{(i)}.

To demonstrate dependence of R on the parameter a, I need to be able to uniquely assign each \phi^{(i)} a coefficient Z_i.  It doesn't matter how I do this assignation, since all of the Z's are identically distributed, but the assignation needs to be unique and it cannot depend on the corresponding value of \lambda_i, since that will depend on the parameter a.

The analytic solution is easy: just compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues for arbitrary a, choose a specific realization of R by specifying my Z's, and watch how that realization of R depends on a.  (For the toy model, R will generally become more rapidly varying as a increases.)

The problem here is how to implement this numerically.  Numpy apparently scrambles the eigenvectors as it does its computation, so there's no way to uniquely tag them.  I'm guessing that the only way to do this is to dig into the underlying code and specifically implement some type of arbitrary tagging function.

To put the problem succinctly: I need a way of ordering the eigenvectors produced by numpy which doesn't depend upon the magnitude of the associated eigenvalue.

Is there a way to do this?

**Update:**
I've managed to find a partial answer to this problem, but I'll need to do some more research for the full answer.  It looks like I'm going to have to implement my own algorithm for this.

For matrices of the type I'm considering, the Lanczos algorithm (for a given choice of initial vector) is deterministic and the steps do not depend on choice of my parameter.  That gives me a symmetric, tridiagonal matrix to solve eigenvalues for.

Divide-and-conquer might work here.  It seems like I could implement a version of it which would allow me to track the eigenvectors independent of the associated eigenvalue.  The "divide" part, at least, can be implemented in a deterministic, parameter-independent way, but I'll need to learn much more about the "conquer" part of the algorithm to know for sure.

Comment: I guess you have to reorder the eigenvectors yourself, since there is no natural order of eigenvalues or eigenvectors. Numpy cannot know what order you expect, since it doesn't know your problem.

Comment: Actually, I don't care about the order; I just care that the order is predictable.  For any matrix, you can tag each eigenvector/eigenvalue based on how it depends on the specific components of the matrix; if there were a way of telling numpy to order by this tag, that would be enough.  It might even be sufficient to tell numpy not to reorder at all, depending on how it implements the linalg.eigh() function, but I don't know enough about th inner workings of the algorithm to do that, and I really, really don't want to have to implement my own eigenmatrix algorithm for this.

Comment: The point is that numpy doesn't know about your parameter. All it gets is a numerical matrix which it diagonalizes. There is no sensible definition of an order of eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

Comment: Yes.  I'm aware of that.  My point is that I don't care about the order being sensible, I merely care about it being predictable.  If I knew how numpy was reordering things under the hood, I'd be done.

My guess here is that the only answer is to start tearing apart LAPACK and rewriting it to my specifications.  I was hoping that there was a way around this.

Comment: The only sensible way of ordering is to order them by magnitude, which is what numpy is doing. Another way of seeing the problem is to look at the characteristic equation, which is a polynomial whose zeros define the eigenvalues. The coefficients of this polynomial will depend on the parameter you are varying. There is no order of these zeros wrt to the parameter! Specifically, there might be situations where zeros are identical (degeneracies). How is the order defined in such a case? I'm afraid your problem is ill-posed and you have to think more closely about what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I would truly like to be able to do is solve for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors without specifying the parameter at all; then it would be trivial to assign each eigenvector a coefficient in my expansion, and watch the dependence of the process change as the parameter varied.  This isn't a plausible solution for large matrices.  Thus, I need a way to track eigenvectors absent this.  I don't care how the ordering is defined (it can even be arbitrary) as long as I have a way of tagging the eigenvectors.

Comment: I don't understand your notion of `tagging eigenvectors`. I guess I generally don't understand what your goal is.

Comment: This can be done; the problem is not under-determined or ill-posed.  A conceptually simple way of doing it is to compute the eigenvectors of an arbitrary NxN matrix, and assign each one a tag based on it's dependence upon specific components of the matrix.  However, this is not computationally simple for large matrices.  What I'm probably going to need to do is dig into the guts of LAPACK itself and write a tracker for the various manipulations which go on, but, as I said before, I was hoping there was an easier way.  Based on your responses, I guess the answer is no.

Comment: I still doubt that there even is a principle way of generally achieving what you want. I don't understand this sentence: ` assign each one a tag based on it's dependence upon specific components of the matrix`. Generally, every eigenvector will non-linearly depend on all matrix components.

Comment: Here's an example: for the 2x2 matrix [[a,b],[b,c]], the eigenvectors are [-(-a+c+(a^2+4*b^2-2*a*c+c^2)^(1/2))/(2*b),1] and [-(-a+c-(a^2+4*b^2-2*a*c+c^2)^(1/2))/(2*b),1].  I can assign them labels + and - irrespective of the choice of a,b,c (and independent of which has the higher eigenvalue) as a means of tracking them.  Generalize this to NxN; this is all I need to be able to do.

Comment: What you show is only one choice, since eigenvalues may coincide for special values of `a,b,c` and there are thus several branches that you may stitch together whatever way you want. This arbitrariness becomes more pronounced in higher dimensions.

Comment: I don't care that it's arbitrary.  I merely care that it's possible; which it is.  Now I need to find a way to implement it.  (Sorry, this short response format isn't really conducive to me giving a full explanation of why this matters.  Is there a way to send private messages?)

Comment: If you just want a continuous representation of the eigenvalue in dependence of the matrix, the current implementation gives you that! Ordering eigenvalues by magnitude ensures that infinitesimal changes in the matrix change each eigenvalue infinitesimal.

Comment: It's not the eigenvalues that matter, it's the associated eigenvectors.  As I change the parameter continuously, I will eventually reach a point where the eigenvalue of one eigenvector passes the eigenvalue of another eigenvector.  If the eigenvectors are ordered by magnitude of corresponding eigenvalue, whenever this happens they will reorder themselves, and thus be assigned a different coefficient in my code.  That's what I must prevent.

Comment: Alright, I now think I have a better idea of what you want to achieve. I think your request is still ill-posed for cases where eigenvalues are exactly identical (since the associated eigenvalues span a multidimensional space in this case), but as far as I understand you are more interested in keeping "similar" eigenvectors with the same tag while crossing such degeneracies. I guess your best bet would be to reorder the eigenvalues of two nearby parameter points by minimizing the distance between eigenvectors (thus identifying similar ones).

Comment: It's not clear that what I understand you want can be done in general, see [this question for example](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43124/conditions-for-smooth-dependence-of-the-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-a-matrix). Besides, numpy does not even guarantee that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are ordered. Maybe you could assign some arbitrary tags, and as you vary the parameter, assign the updated tags by minimising some kind of global distance? I don't know how well that'd work in practice, though.

Comment: Because the matrix is real, symmetric, positive-definite, and there is only one parameter, then the eigenvalues will be smoothly varying (as should the eigenvectors, but I'm not as certain about this).  I agree that tagging by global distance would work, but it's computationally prohibitive; for the full problem I can only afford to populate the matrix a few times, so I can't check for every crossing.  I need a way to tag at a lower level.

Comment: Interesting. A good place to ask this kind of "scientific computing" questions is http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, I've managed to come up with two partial answers to this problem.

The first is that, for a real symmetric matrix with no zero eigenvectors (it might also be necessary to specify non-degenerate), it should be feasible to generate an algorithm for solving the eigenpair problem which generates eigenpairs in a fixed order independent of the choice of matrix.  Given a constant starting vector, the [Lanczos algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) will produce a tridiagonal matrix for an arbitrary real, symmetric matrix in a deterministic way.  The "divide" part of the [divide-and-conquer algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_eigenvalue_algorithm) is similarly deterministic, which means that the only part of the algorithm for which the number of iterations depends on the values of the elements of the matrix is the "conquer" portion, solving the secular equation:

1+\sum_j^m w_j^2/(d_j-\lambda)=0

Thus, for each 2x2 block, the problem boils down to how to order the two roots of the secular equation in a way that doesn't actually depend on the values of the original matrix.

The second partial solution is much easier to implement, but more prone to fail.  In retrospect, it's also obvious.

Two different eigenvectors of the same matrix will always be orthogonal to each other.  Thus, if the eigenvectors smoothly vary as a function of a single parameter a, then:

v_i(a).v_j(a+da) = \delta_{ij} + O(da)

Thus, this gives a natural mapping between eigenvectors as the parameter a varies.

This is similar to the idea David Zwicker and jorgeca suggested of measuring global distance between pairs of eigenvectors, but much easier to implement.  However, implementations of this will be prone to failure in regions where the eigenvectors are rapidly varying or if the change in the parameter a is too large.

Also, the question of what happens at crossings of eigenvalues is interesting, because at each such crossing the system becomes degenerate.  However, within the set of allowed eigenvectors spanning the degeneracy, there will be two which satisfy the dot product condition and which can be used as the basis spanning the degeneracy, thus maintaining the mapping.

This is, of course, assuming that it is correct to treat the eigenvectors as smooth continuous functions on the parameter space, which (as jorgeca pointed out) I'm not certain can be assumed.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well you are looking for the eigenvalues \lambda(t) of matrices A(t) given by entries that are continuous functions of a real variable t.

Let me to recommend you to consult the books:

[1] R. Bathia: Matrix analysis, Springer. Chapter VI?

[2] T. Kato: A short introduction to perturbation theory of linear operators, Theorem 5.2 of Chapter II.

[3] D. Hinrichsen, A. Pritchard: Mathematical systems theory, Vol. 1, Corollary 4.1.19.

Comment: Its great to recommend books, but could you also answer with maybe some knowledge you've gotten through reading these books, and use the books as reference? Its hard to get one's hands on books especially just to answer a question