# Eigenvalues not following order while changing parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, eigenvalue

I have a `6x6` matrix `H` of which two eigenvalues become complex at certain values of the parameter `l` (for lambda). Apparently they are the first two elements of the eigenvalue array `E` we after diagonalizing `H` (calling `np.linalg.eig` module). However, this sequence is not maintained when they become real (in my case, when `l` is between -1 and 1). I can track them by comparing them to the exact analytical expressions.

See my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath

dim=6; t=1.0; eps=0.5; U = 2.0

# Initialize H
H=np.zeros((dim,dim),float)

# Vary parameter l
for l in np.linspace(-2,2,3):

    # Construct H-matrix (size: 6 x 6)
    tm=t-l; tp=t+l

    H[0][0]=H[2][2]=H[3][3]=H[5][5]=2.0*eps
    H[1][1]=H[4][4]=2.0*eps+U
    H[1][2]=H[2][4]=tm
    H[2][1]=H[4][2]=tp
    H[1][3]=H[3][4]=-tm
    H[3][1]=H[4][3]=-tp

    # Diagonalize H 
    E,psi=np.linalg.eig(H)

    # Print all the eigenvalues 
    print('lambda=',l,'===>')
    print()
    print('First two eigenvalues: E0=',E[0], 'E1=',E[1] )
    print('Always real eigenvalues: E2=',E[2], 'E3=',E[3], 'E4=',E[4], 'E5=',E[5] )
    print()


    print("Expected sometimes complex eigenvalues:")
    print("2\eps+[U+\srqt{16(t^2-\lambda^2)+U^2}]/2=",2.0*eps+(U+cmath.sqrt(16*tp*tm+U**2) )*0.5,"degeneracy=1")
    print("2\eps+[U-\srqt{16(t^2-\lambda^2)}+U^2]/2=",2.0*eps+(U-cmath.sqrt(16*tp*tm+U**2) )*0.5,"degeneracy=1")


    print("Expected always real eigenvalues:")
    print("2\eps=",2.0*eps,"degeneracy=3")
    print("2\eps+U=",2.0*eps+U,"degeneracy=1")
    print('---------------------')
    print()
```

How can I maintain the sequence so that I can plot only the "sometimes complex" pair of eigenvalues against `l` (or lambda)?

Output:

```
lambda= -2.0 ===>

First two eigenvalues: E0= (2.0000000000000058+3.3166247903554043j) E1= (2.0000000000000058-3.3166247903554043j)
Always real eigenvalues: E2= (2.9999999999999982+0j) E3= (0.9999999999999999+0j) E4= (1+0j) E5= (1+0j)

Expected sometimes complex eigenvalues:
2\eps+[U+\srqt{16(t^2-\lambda^2)+U^2}]/2= (2+3.3166247903554j) degeneracy=1
2\eps+[U-\srqt{16(t^2-\lambda^2)}+U^2]/2= (2-3.3166247903554j) degeneracy=1
Expected always real eigenvalues:
2\eps= 1.0 degeneracy=3
2\eps+U= 3.0 degeneracy=1
---------------------

lambda= 0.0 ===>

First two eigenvalues: E0= -0.23606797749979025 E1= 2.9999999999999996
Always real eigenvalues: E2= 4.236067977499788 E3= 1.0 E4= 1.0 E5= 1.0

Expected sometimes complex eigenvalues:
2\eps+[U+\srqt{16(t^2-\lambda^2)+U^2}]/2= (4.23606797749979+0j) degeneracy=1
2\eps+[U-\srqt{16(t^2-\lambda^2)}+U^2]/2= (-0.2360679774997898+0j) degeneracy=1
Expected always real eigenvalues:
2\eps= 1.0 degeneracy=3
2\eps+U= 3.0 degeneracy=1
---------------------

lambda= 2.0 ===>

First two eigenvalues: E0= (2.000000000000008+3.3166247903554043j) E1= (2.000000000000008-3.3166247903554043j)
Always real eigenvalues: E2= (2.999999999999997+0j) E3= (1+0j) E4= (1+0j) E5= (1+0j)

Expected sometimes complex eigenvalues:
2\eps+[U+\srqt{16(t^2-\lambda^2)+U^2}]/2= (2+3.3166247903554j) degeneracy=1
2\eps+[U-\srqt{16(t^2-\lambda^2)}+U^2]/2= (2-3.3166247903554j) degeneracy=1
Expected always real eigenvalues:
2\eps= 1.0 degeneracy=3
2\eps+U= 3.0 degeneracy=1
---------------------
```

PS: Please let me know if my question is not clear or if it needs to get reorganized.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17105436/7207392 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165167

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the documentation:
 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html

I quote:

> ... The eigenvalues are not necessarily ordered. The resulting array will be of complex type, unless the imaginary part is zero in which case it will be cast to a real type. When a is real the resulting eigenvalues will be real (0 imaginary part) or occur in conjugate pairs

Therefore, if you want to keep the order and you know that there is a continous change of the real part of the eigenvalues with respect to the parameters, what you need to do is sort the eigenvectors by key, where the key is just given by the real part of the eigenvalues:

```
vals, eigs = np.linalg.eig(H);
eigs = eigs[ np.argsort( np.real(vals) ) ]
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Nope, I still get 

`lambda= 0.0 ===>

First two eigenvalues: E0= -0.23606797749979025 E1= 2.9999999999999996`

where I expect `E1=4.23606797749979`.