# Eigensystem of parametrized, hermitian matrix in python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, lapack, eigenvalue

Suppose we are interested in the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a hermitian matrix h(t) that depends on a parameter t. My matrix is large and sparse and hence needs to be treated numerically.

A **naive approach** is to evaluate the matrix h(t_k) at discretized parameter values t_k. Is it possible to sort the eigenvectors and eigenvalues according to the "character of the eigenvector"?

Let me illustrate what I mean by "character of the eigenvector" with the following simple example (i denotes the imaginary unit).

h(t) = {{1, i*t}, {-i*t, 1}}

The eigenvalues are 1-t and 1+t with the corresponding eigenvectors {-i, 1} and {i, 1}. Hence sorting according to the "eigenvector character" the eigenvalues should cross at t = 0. However most eigensolvers sort them by increasing eigenvalues exchanging the eigenvectors from negative to positive t (see code and output plot).

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sla
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def h(t):
    # parametrized hermitian matrix
    return np.array([[1, t*1j], [-t*1j, 1]])


def eigenvalues(t):
    # convert to tuple for np.vectorize to work
    return tuple(sla.eigsh(h(t), k=2, return_eigenvectors=False))

eigenvalues = np.vectorize(eigenvalues)

t = np.linspace(-1, 1, num=200)
ev0, ev1 = eigenvalues(t)

plt.plot(t, ev0, 'r')
plt.plot(t, ev1, 'g')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('eigenvalues')

plt.show()
```

[image: output plot]

**Idea**
Most eigensolvers iteratively approximate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. By feeding the eigensystem of the matrix h(t_k) to the solver as an initial guess to diagonalize h(t_{k+1}) one might obtain a result ordered by the "character of the eigenvector".

Is it possible to achieve this with scipy or more generally with python? Preferentially the heavy diagonalization should be delegated to a dedicated compiled library (e.g. Lapack in scipy). Is there a suitable Lapack routine maybe already wrapped in scipy?

Is there an alternative method that achieves the same? How can it be implemented in python?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17105436/7207392

Comment: Related with more parameters: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8403/continuity-of-eigenvectors-of-parametric-matrix

Comment: Technically this is called "tracking eigensystem/eigenmode". Possible method [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7473849&tag=1)

Comment: Matlab method [eigenshuffle](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22885-eigenshuffle) to properly permute eigensystem at each parameter value. Drawback is to calculate all eigenvalues instead of following just the desired ones.